# C++/WinRT DataGrid

Tags: c++-winrt

We are building a pretty complex application using C++/WinRT, with the plan to transition to WinUI down the road.  The application has various places where it needs pretty comprehensive and sophisticated table view functionality.

Ideally we would use a C++/WinRT "native" table view, but there doesn't seem to be such an entity.

We have briefly researched the possibility of embedding a Windows Community Toolkit DataGrid under a "C# Island", but we are looking for other options or better paths forward.

What are the current best practices for supporting powerful table views (lots of rows and columns, sorting, column reordering, inline editing, etc.) in a C++/WinRT application?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, you have to make it. [XAML custom (templated) controls with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/xaml-cust-ctrl) is a short introduction into the topic.

Comment: Fer sures.  We have already implemented several custom controls for our application suite which are clearly specific to our functionality by going this route.  Since "DataGrid"/"TableView" functionality is quite common and at the same time deep, complex, and tricky to implement, we are curious as to how other applications approach this need, specifically in the C++/WinRT environment.

Comment: There's [Telerik UI for WinUI](https://www.telerik.com/winui) and [Telerik UI for UWP](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui). I don't know if there are any issues when using them in a native application.

Comment: As I understand things, UWP would require like a "C# Island" (https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Sample-Windows-CppWinRT), though the WinUI route might be interesting...

Comment: That's incorrect. The Windows Runtime (as well as UWP as a client) has *always* been a native platform. This has been poorly communicated by Microsoft. You absolutely can write a UWP application with C++. The Windows Community Toolkit is the odd one out really, that somehow managed to restrict itself to .NET. As far as the UWP goes, there is no CLR in it anywhere. .NET has always been an external dependency.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it is the ".NET-ness" of the WCT that makes it require a "C# Island bridge.  Thanks for helping to clear the confusion.  It seems we have the following options: *(A)* DataGrid from WCT via C# Bridge (free but a real pain), _(B)_ Telerik UI (paid), _(C)_ WinUI 3 Controls by DevExpress (free for now but paid later), _(D)_ Syncfusion WinUI DataGrid (paid), or _(E)_ Wait for the WinUI team to finally publish one (https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1500) (free but who knows when).